# how handler mapping works in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, aop

I am new to spring mvc. I am debugging a mvc code as given below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController extends BroadleafRegisterController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("registrationForm") RegisterCustomerForm registerCustomerForm) {
        return super.register(registerCustomerForm, request, response, model);
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("registrationForm") RegisterCustomerForm registerCustomerForm, BindingResult errors) throws ServiceException, PricingException {
        return super.processRegister(registerCustomerForm, errors, request, response, model);
}

@ModelAttribute("registrationForm") 
public RegisterCustomerForm initCustomerRegistrationForm() {

return super.initCustomerRegistrationForm();        

}

}
```

above is a spring handler class. for /register request i was thinking regsister() method should called but before this method inintcustomerRegisterationForm() is called i do not know why and how this method is called. I searched this in google but not find any useful information. I think this is like a interceptor method as in struts2. Please tell us how this method is called

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The initCustomerRegistrationForm() is being called because it is the 'model' of your controller.  The model is typically always need for a get and post request for a specific form and represents the data entered into the form.

If you want your form pre-populated with some data, then you would add that data to the 'model'.  The 'model' is also what is submitted to the post request then submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

According to spring documentation

***@ModelAttribute methods are used to populate the model with commonly needed attributes for example to fill a drop-down with states or with pet types, or to retrieve a command object like Account in order to use it to represent the data on an HTML form.
A controller can have any number of @ModelAttribute methods. All such methods are invoked before @RequestMapping methods of the same controller.***

Which explains why the initCustomerRegistrationForm() method is called before request mapping methods.